# TableView gets messed up when changing row height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, tableview

i am facing a very strange bug in my tableView. When changing the row height, the content gets mixed up very strangely (see the GIF).
[image]

Here is the code for my tableView, I think I have all labels, imageViews etc. properly resetted at the beginning. I added the Task @ MainAnchor method but it didnt change anything.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailVerbindungTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! detailVerbindungTableViewCell
    Task { @MainActor in
        
        for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if let label = view as? LineHalfTriangleView {
                label.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        for view in cell.sideLineView.subviews {
            cell.sideLineView.willRemoveSubview(view)
        }
        
        var arrayIndex = indexPath.row / 2
        print(arrayIndex)
        let middleSeperator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.contentView.frame.height / 2, width: cell.contentView.frame.width, height: 1))
        middleSeperator.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        var sideLineType = "end"
        let timeFormatHHMM = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatHHMM.timeStyle = .short
        var sideColor = UIColor.clear
        var sideTopColor = UIColor.clear
        var sideBottomColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.devLabel.text = "\(arrayIndex)"
        cell.devLabel.isHidden = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "devDetailVerbIndex")
        cell.lineNumberLabel.text = ""
        cell.lineNumberLabel.textColor = .label
        cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        cell.destinationLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeTopLabel.text = ""
        cell.constDestToNumber.constant = 8
        cell.constDestToStrich.constant = 58
        cell.constDestToNumber.isActive = true
        cell.destinationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: cell.destinationLabel.font.pointSize)
        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            //Location cell
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            cell.constDestToNumber.isActive = false
            cell.constDestToStrich.constant = 8
            cell.destinationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: cell.destinationLabel.font.pointSize, weight: .semibold)
            if arrayIndex == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].count {
                cell.destinationLabel.text = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last?.arrival.name
            } else {
                cell.destinationLabel.text = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departure.name
            }
            if arrayIndex == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].count {
                //Location cell
                //Show Time
                //Last cell
                sideLineType = "end"
                cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last is PublicLeg {
                    print("PublicLeg")
                    var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last as! PublicLeg
                    if tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime == tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime {
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime )
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                } else {
                    print("IndividualLeg")
                    var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last as! IndividualLeg
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempIndLeg.arrivalTime)
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
                }
            } else {
                //Not last cell
                //Location cell
                //Show Time
                if arrayIndex == 0 {
                    sideLineType = "start"
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first?.departureTime == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first?.plannedDepartureTime {
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first!.plannedDepartureTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first?.plannedDepartureTime.distance(to: (resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first?.departureTime ?? resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first?.plannedDepartureTime)!)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].first!.departureTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference?.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    //MARK: Location middle Side Color
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg
                        sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    }
                } else {//MARK: sideLineType Middle
                    sideLineType = "middle"
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = false
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departureTime == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].plannedDepartureTime {
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departureTime)
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].plannedDepartureTime.distance(to: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departureTime )
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departureTime)
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].plannedArrivalTime {
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime )
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg
                        sideBottomColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideBottomColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    }
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] is PublicLeg { //Line before current
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] as! PublicLeg
                        sideTopColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideTopColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Even index
        } else {
            //Info cell
            cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
            sideLineType = "static"
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                //Fahrzeug
                print("PublicLeg")
                var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg
                cell.lineNumberLabel.text = tempPublicLeg.line.label ?? ""
                cell.destinationLabel.text = tempPublicLeg.destination?.name
                if tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2 == nil || tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2 == 0 {
                    
                    cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColorC = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor
                } else {
                    cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColorC = UInt32(UIColor.clear.hexa)
                    let backgroundLineHalfHalf = LineHalfTriangleView(frame: cell.lineNumberLabel.frame)
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.topColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.bottomColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.borderColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.borderColor
                    cell.contentView.addSubview(backgroundLineHalfHalf)
                    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundLineHalfHalf)
                }
                cell.lineNumberLabel.foregroundColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.foregroundColor
                cell.lineNumberLabel.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 0)
                //MARK: Info PublicLeg Time
                if tempPublicLeg.departureTime == tempPublicLeg.plannedDepartureTime {
                } else {
                    let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedDepartureTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.departureTime )
                    cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalWithText()
                    cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeTopLabel.text = "+ \(timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber())"
                    if cell.timeTopLabel.text?.contains("-") == true {
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+ ", with: "")
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "- ")
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                    }
                }
                if tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime == tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime {
                } else {
                    let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime )
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalWithText()
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.text = "+ \(timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber())"
                    if cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.contains("-") == true {
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+ ", with: "")
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "- ")
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                    }
                }
                if cell.timeTopLabel.text == cell.timeBottomLabel.text {
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = cell.timeTopLabel.textColor
                }
                sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                cell.lineNumberLabel.shape = tempPublicLeg.line.style.shape
                
                
                
                //Expandable Cell
                
                let intermediateTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.frame.height, width: cell.frame.width, height: 30))
                intermediateTableView.register(detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell")
                intermediateTableView.dataSource = cell
                intermediateTableView.delegate = cell
                cell.contentView.addSubview(intermediateTableView)
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
            } else {
                //Walk
                print("IndividualLeg")
                var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                cell.destinationLabel.text = "Fußweg: \(tempIndLeg.departure.getDistanceText(CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lat ?? 0)/1000000, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lon ?? 0)/1000000)))"
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.label, .lightGray])
                let walkIconImgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 96, y: 24, width: 42, height: 42))
                walkIconImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                walkIconImgView.image = UIImage(systemName: "figure.walk.diamond")!.applyingSymbolConfiguration(config)
                cell.addSubview(walkIconImgView)
                walkIconImgView.isHidden = true
                let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
                imageAttachment.image = UIImage(systemName: "figure.walk", withConfiguration: config)
                let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
                fullString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment))
                cell.lineNumberLabel.attributedText = fullString
                sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
        }
        
        switch sideLineType {
        case "middle": // ⎡ Comes from bottom to top
            // Create the ⏐ UIView
            let leftView = UIView()
            leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 7, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2)
            leftView.backgroundColor = sideBottomColor
            // Create the ⎯ UIView
            let rightView = UIView()
            rightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 7, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6)
            rightView.backgroundColor = sideBottomColor
            // Add the subviews to the container view
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(leftView)
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(rightView)
            // ⎣ Comes from top to bottom
            // Create the ⏐ UIView
            let topLeftView = UIView()
            topLeftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 11)
            topLeftView.backgroundColor = sideTopColor
            // Create the ⎯ UIView
            let topRightView = UIView()
            topRightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 11, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6)
            topRightView.backgroundColor = sideTopColor
            // Add the subviews to the container view
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(topLeftView)
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(topRightView)
        case "start": // ⎡
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            let sideLineSideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6))
            sideLineSideView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineSideView)
        case "end": // ⎣
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 3))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            let sideLineSideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6))
            sideLineSideView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineSideView)
        case "static": // ⎥
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            
        default: break
        }
    }
        return cell
    
}
```

And with the following method, I change the height:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if expandedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
            expandedRowIndex = -1
            shouldExpanded = false
        } else {
            expandedRowIndex = indexPath.row
            shouldExpanded = true
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == expandedRowIndex && shouldExpanded == true {
            return 91 //Expanded
        }
        return 71 //Not expanded
    }
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: It seems like this code `switch sideLineType {case "middle":` is adding view with fixed frame which is causing the problem, 1. on each cell reuse it adds multiple subview 2. Frames are fixed so when the cell size changes it doesn't expand. So you need build this UI inside the cell using auto layout

Comment: As a general rule, it's a bad idea to add/remove subviews inside `cellForRowAt`. A much better approach is to create them in the cell's `init` and then show/hide/configure them when they are dequeued. It is also a really good idea to use constraints rather than calculating frames. It also appears you are adding (or intending to add) an embedded tableView for your expandable cell? That can be very problematic, and I'd suggest replacing that with a stack view.

Comment: If you show how you want your expanded cell to look I can give you some sample code that you may find helpful. It would also help if you included your data structure with some example data.

Comment: I´ve posted an answer for your comment. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorLobe - FYI -- when posting new code and/or additional information, you should edit your question... not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're missing a lot of information - data structures, sample data, etc. - so I can't copy/paste/run your code to figure out exactly what's wrong.

However, I would **strongly** suggest:

- process your data in your data structure (calculating time differences, etc)
- put your "cell layout" code inside your cell class(es), **not** inside `cellForRowAt`
- don't add/remove subviews inside `cellForRowAt`
- use auto-layout / constraints rather than calculating sizes

and, what I think would really help you...

- use multiple cell classes

For example, instead of ONE cell class that needs add/remove subviews for every instance, use **four** classes (I don't know what your ultimate needs will be, so you might need more). I've added vertical space between the cells to make it clear:

[image]

Now, in each cell's `init` process, create and layout only the UI elements **that cell** will need.

Then, in `cellForRowAt`, dequeue and configure the appropriate class.

Here's how it would look without the inter-cell spacing:

[image]

If that's not quite clear, or if you're still having trouble... if you put together a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (post it somewhere like GitHub) that includes your data structures and some sample data and I can help you find the issue.

Comment: Thank you, sure, I made you an example app and uploaded it on GitHub: https://github.com/victorlobe/BahnfinderVerbindungDemo.git

Comment: @VictorLobe - ok, I made some modifications to your example app, but a question: Will you "walk / Fußweg" row always be only the image and label? or can it also have "intermediate stops"?

Comment: Oh, and.... will the "walk / Fußweg" row ever have a "time label" on the left?

Comment: Thank you very very much for your effort. The Walk row never have any intermediate stops. But the time label is needed for the estimated walk time.

Comment: I noticed a small bug, all Location labels except the first one are showing the content from the last one but everything else is working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @VictorLobe - ah, you must have seen my fork of your repo... I've made a LOT of changes that were not yet pushed. I was going to write up some notes and then tell you to take a look. I just added a ReadMe and pushed latest changes to the "DonMag" branch. Give it a look.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Thank you very much, that's perfect!

Comment: Wow! Much respect for your effort and keep up the good work!

Comment: And one last question. Do you want a credit inside my app?

Comment: @VictorLobe - No need for "credit" ... like many folks who participate here, I'm just glad to offer assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Thank you very much for you comments, I appreciate it!
To the last comment, this is how my cells should look like/look now:
[image]

The data I get comes from a private API Server of the Deutsche Bahn. I've updated my code and now this is my cellForRowAt method:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailVerbindungTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! detailVerbindungTableViewCell
    Task { @MainActor in
        
        for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if let label = view as? LineHalfTriangleView {
                label.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        for view in cell.sideLineView.subviews {
            cell.sideLineView.willRemoveSubview(view)
        }
        
        var arrayIndex = indexPath.row / 2
        print(arrayIndex)
        let middleSeperator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.contentView.frame.height / 2, width: cell.contentView.frame.width, height: 1))
        middleSeperator.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        var sideLineType = "end"
        var sideColor = UIColor.clear
        var sideTopColor = UIColor.clear
        var sideBottomColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.devLabel.text = "\(arrayIndex)"
        cell.devLabel.isHidden = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "devDetailVerbIndex")
        cell.lineNumberLabel.text = ""
        cell.lineNumberLabel.textColor = .label
        cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.intermediateStops.removeAll()
        cell.destinationLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeTopLabel.text = ""
        cell.constDestToNumber.constant = 8
        cell.constDestToStrich.constant = 58
        cell.constDestToNumber.isActive = true
        cell.destinationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: cell.destinationLabel.font.pointSize)
        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            //Location cell
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            cell.constDestToNumber.isActive = false
            cell.constDestToStrich.constant = 8
            cell.destinationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: cell.destinationLabel.font.pointSize, weight: .semibold)
            if arrayIndex == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].count {
                cell.destinationLabel.text = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last?.arrival.name
            } else {
                cell.destinationLabel.text = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex].departure.name
            }
            if arrayIndex == resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].count {
                //Location cell
                //Show Time
                //Last cell
                sideLineType = "end"
                cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last is PublicLeg {
                    print("PublicLeg")
                    var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last as! PublicLeg
                    if tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.predictedTime == nil {
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    } else if tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.plannedTime == tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.predictedTime {
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime )
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    
                    sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                } else {
                    print("IndividualLeg")
                    var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].last as! IndividualLeg
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempIndLeg.arrivalTime)
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
                }
            } else {
                //Not last cell (here is first and every other cell)
                //Location cell
                //Show Time
                if arrayIndex == 0 {
                    //first cell
                    sideLineType = "start"
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg
                        if tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime == nil {
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = .label
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime)
                        } else if tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime == tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime {
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime!)
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                        } else {
                            let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime.distance(to: (tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime ?? tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime)!)
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime!)
                            cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                            if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                                cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                            }
                        }
                        sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempIndLeg.departureTime)
                        cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    }
                } else {//MARK: sideLineType Middle eg. every cell besiddes first and last
                    sideLineType = "middle"
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = false
                    
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg

                        if tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime == nil {
                            cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = .label
                            cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime)
                        } else if tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime == tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime {
                            cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime!)
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.departureStop.plannedTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime! )
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.departureStop.predictedTime!)
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                        sideBottomColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideBottomColor = UIColor.lightGray
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempIndLeg.departureTime)
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    }
                    
                    
                    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] is PublicLeg { //Line before current
                        print("PublicLeg")
                        var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] as! PublicLeg
                        sideTopColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                        if tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.predictedTime == nil {
                            cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = .label
                            cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.plannedTime)
                        } else if tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.plannedTime == tempPublicLeg.arrivalStop.predictedTime {
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else {
                        let timeDifference = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime )
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1].arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                        if timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber().contains("-") == true {
                            cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                        }
                    }
                    } else {
                        print("IndividualLeg")
                        var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex-1] as! IndividualLeg
                        sideTopColor = UIColor.lightGray
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: tempIndLeg.arrivalTime)
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Even index
        } else {
            //Info cell (Vehicle or Walk)
            cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
            sideLineType = "static"
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] is PublicLeg {
                //Fahrzeug
                print("PublicLeg")
                var tempPublicLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! PublicLeg
                cell.lineNumberLabel.text = tempPublicLeg.line.label ?? ""
                cell.destinationLabel.text = tempPublicLeg.destination?.name
                if tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2 == nil || tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2 == 0 {
                    
                    cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColorC = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor
                } else {
                    cell.lineNumberLabel.backgroundColorC = UInt32(UIColor.clear.hexa)
                    let backgroundLineHalfHalf = LineHalfTriangleView(frame: cell.lineNumberLabel.frame)
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.topColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.bottomColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor2
                    backgroundLineHalfHalf.borderColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.borderColor
                    cell.contentView.addSubview(backgroundLineHalfHalf)
                    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundLineHalfHalf)
                }
                cell.lineNumberLabel.foregroundColor = tempPublicLeg.line.style.foregroundColor
                cell.lineNumberLabel.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 0)
                //MARK: Info PublicLeg Time
                if tempPublicLeg.departureTime == tempPublicLeg.plannedDepartureTime {
                    
                } else {
                    let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedDepartureTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.departureTime )
                    cell.timeTopLabel.text = timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalWithText()
                    cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeTopLabel.text = "+ \(timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber())"
                    if cell.timeTopLabel.text?.contains("-") == true {
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+ ", with: "")
                        cell.timeTopLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "- ")
                        cell.timeTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                    }
                }
                if tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime == tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime {
                } else {
                    let timeDifference = tempPublicLeg.plannedArrivalTime.distance(to: tempPublicLeg.arrivalTime )
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.text = timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalWithText()
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.text = "+ \(timeDifference.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber())"
                    if cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.contains("-") == true {
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+ ", with: "")
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.text = cell.timeBottomLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "- ")
                        cell.timeBottomLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
                    }
                }
                if cell.timeTopLabel.text == cell.timeBottomLabel.text {
                    cell.timeTopLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeBottomLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.isHidden = false
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.text = cell.timeTopLabel.text
                    cell.timeMiddleLabel.textColor = cell.timeTopLabel.textColor
                }
                sideColor = UIColor(argb: tempPublicLeg.line.style.backgroundColor)
                cell.lineNumberLabel.shape = tempPublicLeg.line.style.shape
                
                
                
                //Expandable Cell
                
                let intermediateTableView = detailVerbindungIntermediateStopsTableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.frame.height, width: cell.frame.width, height: .zero))
                intermediateTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                intermediateTableView.register(detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell")
                intermediateTableView.dataSource = cell
                intermediateTableView.delegate = cell
                intermediateTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 20
                intermediateTableView.rowHeight = 20
                intermediateTableView.separatorInset.left = 96
                cell.contentView.addSubview(intermediateTableView)
                cell.intermediateStops = tempPublicLeg.intermediateStops
                cell.sideColor = sideColor
                
                let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: intermediateTableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.destinationLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
                let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: intermediateTableView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
                let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: intermediateTableView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
                let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: intermediateTableView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
                cell.contentView.addConstraints([bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, heightConstraint])
                
                
            } else {
                //Walk
                print("IndividualLeg")
                var tempIndLeg = resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][arrayIndex] as! IndividualLeg
                cell.destinationLabel.text = "Fußweg: \(tempIndLeg.departure.getDistanceText(CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lat ?? 0)/1000000, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lon ?? 0)/1000000)))"
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.label, .lightGray])
                let walkIconImgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 96, y: 24, width: 42, height: 42))
                walkIconImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                walkIconImgView.image = UIImage(systemName: "figure.walk.diamond")!.applyingSymbolConfiguration(config)
                cell.addSubview(walkIconImgView)
                walkIconImgView.isHidden = true
                let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
                imageAttachment.image = UIImage(systemName: "figure.walk", withConfiguration: config)
                let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
                fullString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment))
                cell.lineNumberLabel.attributedText = fullString
                sideColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
        }
        
        switch sideLineType {
        case "middle": // ⎡ Comes from bottom to top
            // Create the ⏐ UIView
            let leftView = UIView()
            leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 7, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2)
            leftView.backgroundColor = sideBottomColor
            // Create the ⎯ UIView
            let rightView = UIView()
            rightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 7, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6)
            rightView.backgroundColor = sideBottomColor
            // Add the subviews to the container view
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(leftView)
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(rightView)
            // ⎣ Comes from top to bottom
            // Create the ⏐ UIView
            let topLeftView = UIView()
            topLeftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 11)
            topLeftView.backgroundColor = sideTopColor
            // Create the ⎯ UIView
            let topRightView = UIView()
            topRightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 11, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6)
            topRightView.backgroundColor = sideTopColor
            // Add the subviews to the container view
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(topLeftView)
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(topRightView)
        case "start": // ⎡
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            let sideLineSideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6))
            sideLineSideView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineSideView)
        case "end": // ⎣
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 + 3))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            let sideLineSideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.sideLineView.frame.height / 2 - 3, width: cell.sideLineView.frame.width, height: 6))
            sideLineSideView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineSideView)
        case "static": // ⎥
            let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: cell.sideLineView.frame.height))
            sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
            cell.sideLineView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
            
        default: break
        }
    }
    return cell
    
}
```

This is my didSelectRowAt method:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row / 2 >= resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0].count {
        return
    }
    
    if resultLegArray[selectedIndex][0][indexPath.row / 2] is PublicLeg && indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
        if expandedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
            expandedRowIndex = -1
        } else {
            expandedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    } else {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
}
```

And this my custom tableView Cell that is displayed inside the main cells:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return intermediateStops.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! detailVerbindungIntermediateStopTableViewCell
    cell.stopLabel.text = intermediateStops[indexPath.row].location.name
    if let time = intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.time {
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: time)
    } else {
        cell.timeLabel.text = ""
    }
    let sideLineMainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: 20))
    sideLineMainView.backgroundColor = sideColor
    cell.lineImageView.addSubview(sideLineMainView)
    cell.rightLabel.isHidden = true
    
    if intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime == nil {
        //Keine Live
        cell.timeLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        if let time = intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.plannedTime {
            cell.timeLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: time)
        } else {
            cell.timeLabel.text = ""
        }        } else {
        //Live
        if intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime == intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.plannedTime {
            //Pünktlich
            cell.timeLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            cell.timeLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure!.plannedTime)
        } else {
            //Außerfahrplanmäßige Zeit
            let timeDifference = intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime?.timeIntervalSince(intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure!.plannedTime)
            
            let delayAttString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            var delayString = NSAttributedString()
            var timeString = NSAttributedString()
            let firstKlammer = NSAttributedString(string: "(", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label])
            let secondKlammer = NSAttributedString(string: ")", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label])
            if timeDifference!.stringFromTimeIntervalWithText().contains("-") {
                delayString = NSAttributedString(string: timeDifference!.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber(), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue])
                timeString = NSAttributedString(string: timeFormatHHMM.string(from: (intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime)!), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue])
                cell.timeLabel.textColor = .systemBlue
            } else {
                delayString = NSAttributedString(string: "+\(timeDifference!.stringFromTimeIntervalOnlyNumber())", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemRed])
                timeString = NSAttributedString(string: timeFormatHHMM.string(from: (intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime)!), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemRed])
                cell.timeLabel.textColor = .systemRed
            }
            delayAttString.append(firstKlammer)
            delayAttString.append(delayString)
            delayAttString.append(secondKlammer)
            cell.timeLabel.text = timeFormatHHMM.string(from: (intermediateStops[indexPath.row].departure?.predictedTime)!)
            cell.rightLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.rightLabel.attributedText = delayAttString
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Sorry for that much code, I appreciate your help and hope I gave you the right information.
Thanks!